# same button perform multiple functions using selectors and update button text in iOS objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, button, toggle, selector

How do you make the same button perform more than 1 function depending on certain conditions and accordingly change the text on the button?
How do you do this using selectors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you want to change what method gets called by the state of the button or some other control...

```
-(IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
    if ( someState ) {
        [someObject doSomething];
    }
    else if (someOtherState) {
        [someObject doSomethingElse];
    }
}
```

just call different methods from a central selector. If you're changing the text on your button to signify what it's going to do, you could select the method to use based on the button's text value.

Answer (score 0):

You can add as many actions for a button for a given event as you want.

Call `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` for each selector that is to be run for the event.

```
UIButton *aButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

[aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(firstMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(secondMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: This lets you make one button always do multiple things.  The OP asked about doing multiple things, depending on certain conditions.  AFAIK, that can't be done -- Anurag's answer is the closest thing.  Alternately, make the button call a sort of dispatch method, and let the dispatch method loot at those "certain conditions" and take the appropriate actions.

Comment: @Alex: Could you explain how to go about using a dispatch method, please?

Comment: For example, say I'm building an audio player and I want a single button to act as play and pause depending on whether the track is not playing and when it is playing, respectively. How would I do that? I'm sure that's possible.

Comment: see @Combat's answer. Add only one listener to the button, and inside that listener check the current title of the button from `button.titleLabel.text`, and perform some action depending on that. Then toggle the button text.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html says that the titleLabel is a view. How do I obtain the current text of the Button? I'm getting very confused with UIButton. Please advice.

Comment: Use either `myButton.titleLabel.text` or even better `myButton.currentTitle` to get the current title. A button internally uses a UILabel to show the text. That UILabel object is named `titleLabel` in the button.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the title by the button's currentTitle property.  See:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html

A cleaner way to code, IMHO, would be to have a variable that tells you whether or not you are in PLAYING mode - use that, then your code will not break if you decide to change the button texts.  In fact you would not want to have to look for different text values if you localize for different languages.

Then you can change your variable AND your button label whenever you go from play to pause, etc.